# ListenableFuture - how to wait before return

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Cloud microservice that posts message on a Kafka broker, this microservice is accessible thru a REST api.

I want to return the submit status back to the caller but seems like Java does not await. How to make this to wait either success or failure before my code returns?

Heres the code:

```
kafkaProduc.send("topictest", msg).addCallback(
                new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, ExecutionDataMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, ExecutionDataMessage> result) {
        eresp.status = "ok";
        eresp.msg = "message submitted successfully";
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        eresp.status = "error";
        eresp.msg = "failure while sending data to kafka. exception: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
});
HttpStatus erespStatus = eresp.status == "ok" ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
return new ResponseEntity<ExecutionResponse>(eresp, erespStatus);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback is for when you want an asynchronous result. If you want to block the calling thread, use `future.get()`...

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = template.send("foo", "bar");
try {
    SendResult<String, String> sendResult = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks gary, will try this approach. But let's say the thread is currently blocked and another caller requests the execution method, will spring create a new thread or it will remain blocked?

Comment: If it's REST, the threading is (usually) managed by the web server (e.g. Tomcat) each request gets its own thread. The template is thread-safe.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Kafkaproducer.send returns a future. If you want to wait then perhaps you would prefer the following:

```
kafkaProduc.send("topictest", msg).get(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then failures are likely to raise an exception rather than invoking your on error callback.